# Is there a way to convert sentences into numbers with Python such as changing A to 1 and B to 2 etc

Tags: python

I want to make something that converts an input sentence into a set of numbers.  For example - Hello to 85121215
I'm not sure how to do this.

I've tried this :

```
   codes = ('a':'1','b':'2','c':'3','d':'4','e':'5','f':'6','g':'7','h':'8','i':'9','j':'10','k':'11')
   code = input ('Enter code')
   print (code)
```

but it gives me a syntax error:

```
  File "main.py", line 1
    codes = ('a':'1','b':'2','c':'3','d':'4','e':'5','f':'6','g':'7','h':'8','i':'9','j':'10','k':'11')
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Parenthesis are for tuple : comma-separated value, here you have key:value so it looks a dict and need to be store between brackets {a:b, c:d}

Comment: Perhaps `codes` should be a dict ? `{'a':1', and so on }`

Answer (score 0):

Just use a dict to replace each char with a number.

```
codes = {'a':'1','b':'2','c':'3','d':'4','e':'5','f':'6','g':'7','h':'8','i':'9','j':'10','k':'11'}
code = input('Enter code')
converted_code = ''.join([codes[c] for c in code])
print(converted_code)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because tuple can't be defined as key: values pairs. You should use dictionary instead:

```
codes = {"a":1, "b":2} # populate all your letters here
user_input = input('Enter code')
converted_code = ",".join([codes[l] for l in user_input])
```

bare in mind that if one of the chars in the user inpur doesn't exist in `codes`, an exception will be raised. To use a default replacement use: `codes.get(l, "default_char")`